# Thousands separator on the line chart values

Tags: r

I am plotting a line chart and want to show values on the line chart as well as shown below in the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLQZw.png)

and I used text function to add text above the line chart point.

```
if (input$dates_PandL[2] - input$dates_PandL[1] <= 15) {
    axis.Date(1, at = seq(input$dates_PandL[1], input$dates_PandL[2]+31, by = "days"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    # draw numeric values in the plot
    text(x = df_category()[, "Date"], 
         y = df_category()[, input$category[1]],
         round(df_category()[, input$category[1]], 2), 
         cex = 1.2, pos = NULL)
```

How do I separate the values by 1000s in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Following clarification

To achieve this change:

```
round(df_category()[, input$category[1]], 2)
```

To:

```
format(round(df_category()[, input$category[1]], 2), nsmall=1, big.mark=",")
```

Comment: I dont want to round the text labels to nearest thousand but I want to display text labels using comma separator after thousand. For example: 56789 as 56,789.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Sudhakar. I have edited the code using `format` to fit your need.